# How to determine instruction fetches are allowed or not by page table and EPT in x86-64?

Tags: x86-64, hardware, virtualization, page-tables, ept

[Format of a Page-Table Entry that Maps a 4-KByte Page
Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUYA6.png)

[Format of an EPT Page-Table Entry that Maps a 4-KByte Page
Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGxW1.png)

It seems `EPT.bit2` and `EPT.bit10` are used to determine whether instruction fetches are
allowed or not in Supervisor-mode \ User-mode.

But how do I know an IPA is supervisor-mode linear address or user-mode linear address ? by `U/S` bit in `page table`?

If my understanding is correct, it means we must combine `page table` and `EPT` to judge whether instruction fetches are allowed or not, right?

In `Intel Manual Volume 3C, Chapter 27, 2.3.2 EPT Violations`, The manual describes several situations where fetches are not allowed. I only care about the situations when `VM-execution control = 1`.

---

- The access is an instruction fetch and the EPT paging structures prevent execute access to any of the bytes being fetched. Whether this occurs depends upon the setting of the “mode-based execute control for EPT” `VM-execution control`:

  - If the control is 0, an instruction fetch from a byte is prevented if bit 2 (execute access) was clear in any of the EPT paging-structure entries used to translate the guest-physical address of the byte.
  - If the `control is 1`, an instruction fetch from a byte is prevented in either of the following cases:

    - Paging maps the `linear address of the byte as a supervisor-mode address` and `bit 2(EPT.bit2)` (execute access for supervisor-mode linear addresses) was clear in any of the EPT paging-structure entries used to translate the guest-physical address of the byte.

      Paging maps a `linear address as a supervisor-mode address` if the `U/S flag(of page table)` (bit 2) is 0 in at least one of the paging-structure entries controlling the translation of the linear address.
    - Paging maps the `linear address of the byte as a user-mode address` and `bit 10 (EPT.bit10)`(execute access for user- mode linear addresses) was clear in any of the EPT paging-structure entries used to translate the guest- physical address of the byte.

      Paging maps a `linear address as a user-mode address` if the `U/S flag(of page table)` is 1 in all of the paging-structure entries controlling the translation of the linear address. If paging is disabled (CR0.PG = 0), every linear address is a user-mode address.

---

How can I tell whether an address is `supervisor-mode address` or `user-mode address` here ? By the high bits of the address (0xffff... is supervisor-mode address, 0x0000... is user-mode address)?

In terms of `Page-Table Entry`, `EPT-entry` and `EPT Violations`, can we say this:

1. if `page table`'s `U/S = 0` in `all levels`, then `EPT.bit2  = 1` in `all levels`, fetches are allowed.
2. if `page table`'s `U/S = 1` in `all levels`, then `EPT.bit10 = 1` in `all levels`,
   fetches are allowed.
3. Not allowed under other circumstances

Comment: I didn't read your full question but, if I understood it correctly, it's the privilege of the code that determines user vs supervisor mode. What you see in the page table is another level (actually the first level, the one set up by the Guest OS) of protection. The CPL of the code segment tells the CPU if it's in user o kernel mode. There are a few gotchas due to some automatism but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Using addresses with the high bit set for supervisor mode is a convention, but it doesn't affect anything about how address translation or protection is done.
The CPL (bits 1:0 of the CS register) control whether accesses are supervisor mode or user mode.
If CPL < 3, accesses are supervisor mode access; if CPL = 3, accesses are user-mode accesses.

If "mode-based execute control for EPT" is 1:

1. If paging is disabled or U/S = 1 in all page table levels, and EPT bit 10 = 1 in all EPT levels, fetches are allowed.
2. If CPL < 3, U/S = 0 in any page table level, and EPT bit 2 = 1 in all EPT levels,
   fetches are allowed.

If "mode-based execute control for EPT" is 0:

1. If paging is disabled or CPL < 3 or U/S = 1 in all page table levels, and EPT bit 2 = 1 in all EPT levels, fetches are allowed.

In addition, bit 63 (XD) must be 0 in all page table levels if CR4.PAE is 1.